# Highcharts saying undefined is not a function when trying to add a new chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to put highcharts into my angular app.  I'm getting my data from Google Sheets and returning a promise object from the call to google.  I then call the Highcharts.Chart() method with my options object.

I get the error below when making the call.  I've tried to figure out what's going on but I am currently lost.  I have a prototype that I do not use angular and the chart works great.  When I go and add the line new Highcharts.Chart(options) I get the error below.  I remove that line the error goes away.

Any thoughts/help would be great!

Error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.Chart.init (/highcharts.src.js:11014:4)
    at Object.Chart (/highcharts.src.js:10937:12)
    at data.then.$scope.sheetdata (/js/controllers/controlChartCtrl.js:11:17)
    at wrappedCallback (/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js:10905:81)
    at /angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js:10991:26
    at Scope.$eval (/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js:11906:28)
    at Scope.$digest (/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js:11734:31)
    at Scope.$delegate.__proto__.$digest (<anonymous>:844:31)
    at /angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js:11945:26
    at completeOutstandingRequest (/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js:4098:10)
```

Partial:

```
Features:
<div id="feature"></div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('controlChartCtrl', []).
  controller('ControlChartCtrl', ['$scope', 'GoogleService', function($scope, GoogleService) {
    var data = GoogleService.getData();
    $scope.helloworld = "hello world!";
    data.then(function (data) {
        // create charts here
        var options = getOptionsForChart('Feature', 'feature', data);
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    }, function (error) {
        $scope.sheetdata = error;
    });

    var getOptionsForChart = function (title, div, data) {
        return {
            chart: {
                renderTo: div,
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: title + ' Control Chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'End Dates'
                },
                categories: data.endDates
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Lead Time'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Lead Time',
                data: data.leadTimes
            }]
        };
    } 

}]);
```

Comment: Stupid question: is the library loaded correctly?

Comment: Show your directive. The stack trace clearly indicates the problem is in `js/directives/highcharts.js:14:35`.

Comment: It is possible to reproduce you example as jsFiddle?

Comment: Sorry I removed the directive.  The original post didn't reflect that in the stack trace. I've updated the stack trace to reflect the removed directive. Error: "at data.then.$scope.sheetdata (/js/controllers/controlChartCtrl.js:11:17)" is the following line: "var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);"

Answer (score 15):

I resolved the issue.  The solution is as follows.

Highcharts requires jQuery to function correctly.  When I added the jquery.js file above the highcharts.js file the angular application started to work correctly.

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: You can also use [standalone-framework](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/aEuGP/) then jquery is not required.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianBochan! Add that an an answer and I'll vote for it.

Comment: `Highcharts requires jQuery to function correctly. ` this is not correct.

Answer (score 10):

Highcharts **does not require JQuery** to work (the current answer is wrong), however you need to load the 'standalone framework' library first:

```
define([
    'vnd/highcharts/standalone-framework',
    'vnd/highcharts/highcharts',
], function(){
    ...
}
```

See @Sebastian's jsfiddle for a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/aEuGP/